# How can I suppress blank pages in SQL Reports?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have a SQL Report that insists on printing an extra blank page at the end, even though all the report items should fit on one page.  I tried shortening the elements on the page that is spilling over, but no matter how much I compress them, or how much blank space is left on the first page, SRS still thinks it needs to take up another page as well.  This is annoying because it's such a common problem - all it takes is one mistake to make a report spill over.  So I'm not asking how can I fix this on this one report, but how can I fix this on this and future reports:  Is there a flag or setting I can set to tell SRS "No matter what, never print more than 1 page"?  Or "Suppress blank pages = true"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try removing any 'empty space' from the body.  Shrink the editing surface to be just large enough for all your ReportItems, both height-wise and width-wise.  ReportingServices thinks the space you have in your body is intentional, so it's preserved.

If that doesn't help and you're noticing this issue on 2005, give the [2008 version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&DisplayLang=en) a try.  There's a new property, ConsumeContainerWhitespace that helps reduce blank pages.

Answer (score 12):

In my experiene, it has ALWAYS been that the data I have on the report page is WIDER than the page margins, so it thinks it needs to make a new page... check the margins of your pages and also how far the data is extending on it.  It may not appear that it is to far in the report designer, but I would bet that's the answer.  We're talking PIXELS here, so check that out and see if it helps!

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!, i just spent two days with that problem bugging me out, as it turns out i had too much white space at the right of my report.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Fixed my problem, but who would have thought it?

Answer (score 0):

use `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to `TRUE` in the Report Properties its `FALSE` by default

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at headers & footers.  I was focused on the central part of the report getting all of the columns smaller, but it was a footer that caused the issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is better moved as a comment.